# Doctrine2 - How can I sort dynamicaly the results of a relation?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

### What I need :

I'm building an API that returns users and some relations : I have an entity called "User" which has a lot of relationships. Let's take the "comments" as example :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comments", mappedBy="idClient", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $comments;
```

In some cases, the client wants to get the user data and the comments data in the same query (by adding "comments" to the "include query param), and wants to sort the comments in a specific order. This order is provided by the client in the query params. In this example, the comments must be sorted by id ASC.

`/api/users?include=comments&sort=comments.id`

Note that order ASC is implicit in that case.

I have a `search()` function that build the query :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder($this->elementName);

/* SELECTs */
$selects = $this->getSelects($params);
foreach($selects as $select) {
    $qb->addSelect($select);
}

/* WHEREs */
$wheres = $this->getWheres($params);
foreach($wheres as $where) {
    $qb->andWhere($where);
}

/* ORDER BY */
foreach($sortBy as $column => $order) {
    $qb->addOrderBy($column, $order);
}
/* LIMIT and OFFSET */
$qb->setFirstResult($offset)
    ->setMaxResults($limit);

$query = $qb->getQuery();
$results = $query->getResult();
```

This function is called to get the primary data of the request : the `users` data. Then, the `users` are transformed by a `UserTransformer`, in order to answer the client in a specific format (JSONAPI).
The relationships (as `comments`) are called later by querying the entity is the object transformer :

```
$comments = $user->getComments(); // Returning $this->comments in the User class.
return $this->collection($comments, new CommentsTransformer()); // sends the $comments data to the CommentsTransformer.
```

### What I tried

I tried `addOrderBy()` to the query builder but I get an error because the DQL does not contains any association named comments.id :

```
Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 110 near 'id ASC': Error: Class Foo\Users has no field or association named comments.id
```

Here is the DQL :

```
SELECT e FROM Foo\Users u WHERE [...] ORDER BY u.comments.id ASC
```

Is there any way I can "see" the comments properties and sort the comments on them in my Query ?

Or is there any way I can inject the sort order in my Users class so it can retrieve the comments data in that dynamical order ? like using $user->getComments($sortBy) and then catch the $sortBy in my Users class (or preferably on my entity mother class) and alter the build-in Doctrine request to add my sorting order ?

PS : sorry for (probably) bad english, it's not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply criteria in your getComments function like

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

public function getComments()
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->orderBy(['id' => Criteria::ASC]);

    return $this->comments->matching($criteria);
}
```